# Why does this method not get called on shutdown?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I've written a simple server-client setup, both using WPF for an interface. When the server is closed, I want to react and send a notification to all connected clients. Here's what I'm using to do that:

In the window declaration, I define a `Closing` handler:

```
<Window x:Class="EPQMessenger.Windows.ServerWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
    Title="Messenger: Server" Height="350" Width="700"
    Closing="Window_Closing">
```

In the code-behind for the window, I have the handler itself:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Log("Closing event canceled. Start sending shutdown signals...");
    _server.SendShutdown();
    this.Log("Shutdown signal sending complete. Shutting down.");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

(Note: the `Log` method adds a message to the screen and to a file.)

And the method it calls, `Server.SendShutdown`:

```
public void SendShutdown()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TcpClient> pair in _clients)
        {
            try
            {
                pair.Value.Send(Protocol.GetResponseFromCode(104));
                _console.Log("Sent shutdown signal to {0}", pair.Key);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                _console.Log("Failed to send shutdown to '{0}': {1}", pair.Key, e.Message);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                _console.Log("Failed to send shutdown to '{0}': {1}", pair.Key, e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

(`_console.Log` is the same method as `Log` from the last snippet.)

The problem here is that the clients only sometimes get notified. The event gets fired, and `SendShutdown` gets called - but the clients only sometimes receive the notification, and the log file only sometimes has the "Sent shutdown to..." messages.

The same problem happens if I try to write to the `NetworkStream` synchronously.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183729/why-isnt-my-wpf-closing-event-being-fired-for-system-closes

Comment: how exactly is it being closed? using the big x in the top? alt + f4? is it a child window that is closing when the parent window closes? this info could be useful

Comment: Big red cross @psoshmo

Comment: are you sure it is not hitting the event? if you put a break point there, does it never hit it?

Comment: @psoshmo Thanks, it *is* hitting it turns out

Comment: Then using breakpoints I would just slowly step through your code and try to pinpoint exactly where things are falling apart. Let me know, Im curious what the issue is

Comment: 1. Watch the lifecycle of `_clients`.  Is something else clearing them out, are they getting returned to garbage collector? 2. How big is `_clients`?  If there are only a couple, the code/loop can finish instantly, thus calling `Environment.Exit(0)` instantly; and before anything can actually get sent the application and socket connections will close. Remove `Environment.Exit(0)` and see if you get any better results.  Alternatively, don't cancel the event **and** remove `Environment.Exit(0)` to see if that helps.